# Creating dataSource in Java according to c# code

Tags: c#, java, datasource, sqlconnection

I need to create dataSource in Java and I know that connection to this data base in C# looks like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=exampleds;Initial Catalog=exampleic;Integrated Security=True");
```

I want to understand, how can I make the connection url from the data I have in C# code.

Comment: You can find this really easily by searching the web.  There are dozens of tutorials, many of which will be more informative and educational than answers to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found answer to this question, connection url for this database would be:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://exampleds/exampleic;domain=???
```

Domain name described somewhere in web.config in C# application, driver for this connection would be

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

So, DataSource would be...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://exampleds/exampleic;domain=dName"/>
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Username and password I, personally, have known from administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mkyong","username","password");
```

But you have to initialize JDBC driver first using code like this:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

And I found this code using google during 3 seconds.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Having this string from c# you created connection to Postgre SQL? To localhost? WHY??? I know how to create connection, but, first of all, I don't need connection, i need DataSource, and, second I wanted to understand what connection url should be like.